# Stripe SCA: Charge succeeded but not captured. Why does it lead to confusion for my customers?

Tags: stripe-payments

With [Placing a card on hold without charging](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/creating-payment-intents#placing-a-card-on-hold-without-charging), you are able to use two-step card payments so you can first authorize the card, then wait to capture funds later (up to seven days).

I do this like this:

```
\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => 1099,
  'currency' => 'eur',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'capture_method' => 'manual',
]);
```

But now I don't understand the documentation. It says:

> Card statements from some issuers do not distinguish between authorizations and captured (settled) payments, which can sometimes lead to confusion for your customers.

What does this mean?

Let's say I create a PaymentIntent for 10,99€ and authorize the card, but the buyer leaves the checkout process. Does the buyer see -10,99€ on his bank account until seven days are over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some issuers do not distinguish between authorizations and captured

That basically means that some banks might show their users a "Pending transactions" section on their bank statement for authorizations, before moving it to a "Complete transactions" section. 
Other banks might handle it differently. Some may just show -$10 and then automatically update it to the captured amount some days later.

If the buyer leaves the checkout process but has already authorized the card, (assuming you are using `handleCardPayment` from the default automatic PaymentIntent confirmation), that would still complete the PaymentIntent flow and create an authorization.

Since the authorization is complete, it would show on the bank statement.